# Как сделать выпадающий список с поиском?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Две таблицы связаны между связью один-ко-многим. При заполнении поля связанного с другой таблицей в django админке выпадающий список. Но в связанной таблице очень много записей. Можно ли организовать выпадающий список с поиском?

Comment: если у Вас получилось настроить скиньте пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Django 2.0 и выше встроена возможность изменить "выпадающий список" на "выпадающий список с автозаполнением(поиском)" в админке. 
Для этого в файле admin.py в модели администратора нужно добавить

`autocomplete_fields = ['Имя поля модели']`

Например:

```
class ChoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    autocomplete_fields = ['question']
```

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае вам поможет один из модулей:

- [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects)
- [django-autocomplete-light](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/)

Описание использования доступны по ссылкам.